# Does your father work for the government? vs Do your father work for the government?

Tags: grammar

> Does your father work for the government?

vs

> Do your father work for the government?

Which one of these phrases is correct?

Comment: "Does your father work for *the* government" is the correct phrasing.

Answer (score 4):

English verbs are conjugated in present tense like this:

```
                          singular          plural
                          -------           ------
first-person                I do             we do
second-person             you do        you all do
third-person        he/she/it does         they do
```

so a verb will end with *s* or *es* if it's third person singular only.

The only verb that is different is *to be* which is *I am*, *we are*, *you you/all are*, *he/she/it is* and *they are*.  (Even then the third-person singular is still the only form that ends with *s*.)

Therefore you say "Does your father work for the government" as *father* is third-person singular.

Comment: I am confused because 'Does' here appearing with 'your' not with father.

Comment: @bravo, "your" describes "father" (identifies which father is being referred to), it isn't the subject of anything.

Comment: The subject of a sentence, if one word, has to be a noun.  *Your* is a possessive adjective modifying *father* which is that noun.  Adjectives don't change whether a noun is plural or singular.